# Analytics: what are p502i and wireless transcoders devices?

Tags: iphone, mobile, google-analytics

We are currently running Google Analytics on an iPhone app, and we got two strange devices appearing at several percents: "DoCoMo P502i" and "Google Wireless Transcoder".

What are these strange devices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see the same after implementing the v2 SDK on iPhone. There's not a lot of visits, but enough to do some research.

Google Wireless Transcoder is a project that strips down everything from the page from scripts to styles back to it's bare bones. Some mobile browsers might use the service to reduce the page size before downloading it and showing on mobile devices.

http://www.google.com/gwt/n

It seems that you can instruct Google  Wireless Transcoder to not process your page and instead redirect the user to another webpage using:

```
<link rel="alternate" media="handheld" href=”mobile_page.htm” />
```

*Source:* http://www.elc-seo.com/search-engines/google/mobile-search-the-google-wireless-transcoder/

I'm afraid I couldn't find out much about "DoCoMo P502i yet. It also seems to be related to some kind of Google Proxy. Look at the full UserAgent it uses:

- DoCoMo/1.0/P502i/c10 (**Google CHTML Proxy**/1.0)

*Source:* http://user-agents.my-addr.com/custom_user_agent_lookup-ua_string_analysis_checker_tool.php?i=395&u=DoCoMo_1_0_P502i_c10_Google_CHTML_Proxy_1_0

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the 2.0 beta versions of the Google Analytics SDK for iOS report an iPod touch as a DoCoMo P502i.

I've just set up a new Analytics profile & tested on two devices, and that's what's I'm seeing.

Yup. A sweet phone, the DoCoMo P502i.